# datepicker error occurs when opening editor in kendo grid UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

when I open the editor in kendo grid UI, error occur like below.

> Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function  ..kendo.all.js:1179

```
if (value && value.indexOf('/D') === 0) {
    date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    if (date) {
        date = date[1];
        tzoffset = offsetRegExp.exec(date.substring(1));
        date = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));
        if (tzoffset) {
            tzoffset = parseMicrosoftFormatOffset(tzoffset[0]);
            date = kendo.timezone.apply(date, 0);
            date = kendo.timezone.convert(date, 0, -1 * tzoffset);
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

I guess this is a binding problem.

Below is my code snippet.

1. datasource schema.

   ```
   schema : {
           model : {
               id : "cid",
               fields : {
                   cid : {
                       type : "number"
                   },

                   meainInstDtm : {
                       type : "datetime"
                   },

               }
           }
   ```
2. kendo grid

   ```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
       dataSource : dataSource,
       columns : [ {
           field : "cid",
           title : "CID"
       }, {
           field : "meainInstDtm",
           title : "meainInstDtm",     
           width: 150,
           editor: dateTimeEditor,
           attributes: {
               style: "text-align: center;"
           }
       }, { 
           command: [{name: 'edit'}, { name: 'destroy'}], title: "&nbsp;", width:"180px", filterable:false
       }],
          editable: "popup"
            })
   ```
3. dateTimeEditor

   ```
    function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
         $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
           .appendTo(container)
           .kendoDateTimePicker({});
     }
   ```

I do not know what the problem is. Help me.

Comment: Where is the if statement called? Check the dojo I made here and see if you can reproduce the problem: https://dojo.telerik.com/eVoNa/2

Comment: @MattOG The code at the top is kendo.js.
I do not call the if statement.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that we can test around?

Comment: @CaraTilos https://jsfiddle.net/6q9dqbju/ 
this is my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the schema type to `date` and added conditions inside edit event. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1e4kung/2/) works for me.

Comment: when it modified `datetime` type  to `date` type, it occur same error...

Comment: Here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define

States the type has to be date, not datetime:
options.fields.fieldName.type String
Specifies the type of the field. The available options are "string", "number", "boolean", "date" and "object". The default is "string".

Comment: Try this [http://jsfiddle.net/v1e4kung/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/v1e4kung/2/). I didn't encounter the error.